# Share a string between methods in C#

Tags: c#

Does anybody knows a way to share a string between methods in C#?

This is the piece of code where I need the get my string:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The screenshot will be stored in this bitmap.
        Bitmap capture = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height);

        // The code below takes the screenshot and
        // saves it in "capture" bitmap.
        g = Graphics.FromImage(capture);
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, screenBounds);

        // This code assigns the screenshot
        // to the Picturebox so that we can view it
        pictureBox1.Image = capture;

    }
```

In here in need the get the 'capture' string:

```
        Bitmap capture = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height);
```

And place 'capture' from this method:

```
   private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(!!!Put Capture in Here!!!))
            {
                color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.FillEllipse(color, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
            }
        }

    }
```

In here:

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(!!!Put Capture in Here!!!))
```

I hope someone can help!

PS: If you don't understand the whole thing, I'm 14 and from the netherlands, So i'm not the best English writer :-).

Comment: place `private Bitmap capture;` within the `class` (and not a method) then reference it within each function using `this.capture`/`capture`.

Comment: You allready use `paint` as class field. Do the same with `capture`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at *scope* of variables.

Your variable `capture` is defined at the method level, and therefore only available that method.

You can define the variable at the class level (outside of the method) and all of the methods within your class will have access to it.

```
Bitmap capture;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The screenshot will be stored in this bitmap.
    capture = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height);

    // The code below takes the screenshot and
    // saves it in "capture" bitmap.
    g = Graphics.FromImage(capture);
    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, screenBounds);

    // This code assigns the screenshot
    // to the Picturebox so that we can view it
    pictureBox1.Image = capture;

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (paint)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(capture))
        {
            color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            g.FillEllipse(color, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Be sure to dispose of your `Bitmap` when you are done with it or you could run in to errors when you run out of GDI resources.